# Fourier Series Complex Algebraic Expressions Help

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers, fourier-series

$$\dfrac {j \,n\pi}{(1+j \, n \pi)} \left(\dfrac {2}{n\pi}\right) (1 - \cos(n \pi))\angle -90° = \dfrac {2(1-\cos(nπ))}{(\sqrt{1+n^2 \pi^2}\angle (90°-\tan^{-1}(n \pi)-90°)}$$

[Complex expression more legible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROYkM.png)

How can one simply get the magnitude and phase angle from the expression on the left hand side. I am having trouble separating the real and imaginary components. When I am able to do this they are always overwhelming expressions whose magnitude is difficult to get.

Comment: How do you understand the meaning of angle marks that appear in both sides of the equation?

Comment: This expression is already in the phasor domain. The part to the left of the angle sign is the amplitude of the cosine wave. The part to the right of the angle sign is the phase shift of the cosine wave. This is all at a set frequency.